# Why fork counter not reset after delete forked repo on GitHub?

Tags: github, git-fork

I forked repo and deleted it, but forks counter on source repo stays the same - not as expected.

After deleting my fork repo it is not listed in source forks - as expected.

My question: is there a way to reset forks counter?

[image]

[image]